# Do I need any special approval to operate my own MLS or IDX system?

Tags: web-services, industry-standard

I'm currently building a enterprise MLS / IDX system and I'm just wondering if there is any type of special considerations to be taken outside of outputting the data in the forms that external web services want to use/consume etc.

I'm wondering if I need to register the system or have it approved by anything?  Right now planned integration will integrate with a number of system.  These systems ask for a MLS number often.

Right now we have a Listing ID in our system as well as a UID for our records.  Is there some sort of global listing ID service or does my specific MLS software system supply our listing ID's and UID's for these data requirements?

If you would like to know more about MLS or IDX I've included a couple links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Data_Exchange

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_listing_service

My main concern is integrating with these external services and ensuring the data we are providing is accurate to the MLS / IDX ecosystem.

Comment: Think the question is on-topic but I wonder if you will get good answers in this format  as it's very specific to a particular industry (real estate in the USA)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, real estate boards have strict requirements if you are to be given access to the MLS data. If you already have access, that means you had to sign a contract which should clearly outline these requirements.

For example, the Canadian Real Estate Agency (CREA) requires some of the following:

1. You cannot allow consumers to write comments or reviews about a particular listing or display a link to such comments or reviews.
2. You must monitor your websites for signs of "scraping," which is the use of a software program or other method to extract Listing Content, such as photographs and/or text from a website
3. You must implement web traffic monitoring and recording code which allows CREA to collect traffic information.
4. You must display trademark information on every page, such as: "The trademarks MLS®, REALTOR®, and the associated logos are owned or controlled by The Canadian Real Estate Association. Used under license."

There are many more rules, which will be unique to whatever real estate board you're getting your MLS data from.